# Source of google analytics call

Tags: gatling

Am pretty sure I dont have any google analytics hooks in my tests, but am wondering the source of the below messages

```
15:25:08.883 [New I/O worker #1] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.n.r.NettyConnectListener - Using non-cached Channel [id: 0x20706c2d, /10.40.36.87:53126 => ssl.google-analytics.com/216.58.197.72:443] for POST '/collect'
15:25:08.937 [New I/O worker #1] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.netty.handler.HttpProtocol -

Request DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: java/1.8.0_60
Content-Length: 135
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: ssl.google-analytics.com
Accept: */*

Response DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 09:55:08 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Sun, 17 May 1998 03:00:00 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: image/gif
Server: Golfe2
Content-Length: 35
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25"

15:25:08.938 [New I/O worker #1] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.n.channel.ChannelManager - Adding key: https://ssl.google-analytics.com:443 for channel [id: 0x20706c2d, /10.40.36.87:53126 => ssl.google-analytics.com/216.58.197.72:443]
```

These lines are printed even before a line such as below

```
Simulation com.xx.xx.CustomSimulation started...
```

Am running this as a gradle project and the above is console output.

Answer (score 0):

This is something added in to gatling itself as the authors want to keep track of how gatling is used. If you want to get rid of it you can either set enableGA = false in the gatling.conf configuration file or set a system variable.

Since I am also using gatling from gradle I set the system variable on the gradle command line (gradlew -DenableGA=false) then pass all the system variables to gatling in the javaexec call i.e.:

```
task gatling(dependsOn: 'compileTestScala') << {
    javaexec {
        main = 'io.gatling.app.Gatling'
        systemProperties System.getProperties()
        .
        .
    }
}
```